# How can I count records in multiple tables having same column for where clause is pgsql

Tags: php, postgresql

I am using postgre sql and phpPgAdmin for my database.

I have a table where i added some table names like:

*table_lsts*

**id name tablename**

**11 abbc table1**

**22 xyyz table2**

**33 deef table3**

now in table1, table2, table3 i have multiple records having a common column named as vpvc_id.

my problem is i have to write a query which first of all get all table names from table_lsts.

then count record in those table where vpvc_id in (*some ids here*) etc

can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_records (ids_lst character varying)
 RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$declare 
 query character varying;
 result integer;
 BEGIN 
   -- First query that create a dynamic query on all tables of table_lsts
    select into query 'select count(*) from (' || String_agg('select vpc_id from '||tablename,' UNION ALL ') || ') a where vpc_id in ('||ids_lst||')' from table_lsts ;
 ---execute dynamic query
 execute query  into result;
return result;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

And use it like this :

```
 select count_records('2,5')
```